# Getting "The page cannot be displayed" (Action cancelled) error when redirecting to another page

Tags: iis, response.redirect

We're running ASP.Net (1.1) on a server with Windows Server 2003 R2 (Service Pack 2).  We have an application (http://newserver.yourdomain.com/someapp) that performs a relatively basic process of taking the user-entered input and populates the data into the database.  If there is a problem with the INSERT/UPDATE, a TRY...CATCH block will trap the error and redirect the user to a centralized "Error Handler" application (http://newserver.yourdomain.com/ErrorHandler) that displays a more user-friendly error screen and log all the relevant information.  The Error Handler resides on the same server and runs ASP.Net (1.1) as well.

This has been working for years, but we're upgrading the servers and replicating all the same applications from the old server (http://oldserver.yourdomain.com) to the new server.  For some reason, now when the application is attempting to redirect the user to the Error handler (via Response.Redirect), we're running into a "The page cannot be displayed" error (aka "Action Cancelled" error).  I assume it's a configuration setting, but I can't think of what it might be.

To make things stranger, this happens in IE6 and IE7, but not in Chrome 12.  Also, we can avigate directly the Error Handler URL without a problem.  The issue seems to center around the need to redirect to that location.

Also, if I set up the old server (http://oldserver.yourdomain.com) to point to the new Error Handler (http://newserver.yourdomain.com/ErrorHandler), it works fine.  The redirection seems to only be an issue on this new server.

Can you think of what the issue(s) might be?

Comment: It may be a security / trust issue. A redirect may not be allowed to redirect to a domain different from where the client is. Are you definitely using just subdomain changes as you've suggested?

Comment: Ash, we're attempting to redirect TO http://newserver.yourdomain.com/ErrorHandler, FROM within http://newserver.yourdomain.com/SomeApp

Comment: I'm clutching at straws here, but it may be that newserver.yourdomain.com is not a "Trusted Site" in IE, so you could try looking at your trusted sites config.

Comment: I tried the trusted sites, but the company's security policy already includes "*yourdomain.com" in the trusted sites configuration.